# What is the formula for determining how many errors a generator matrix can correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, cryptography, coding-theory

I am wondering whether or not there is a generic formula for determining how many errors a generator matrix is able to correct if also provided the field the code is in. For example, given the following generator matrix applied to a code in F4:

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 2\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}

Is there a way to figure out how many errors it can correct?

Comment: Your generator matrix, as written seems to have elements from integers mod 4 not from $GF(4)$.

Comment: @kodlu Updated the problem statement.

Comment: GF(4) whih is the same as $F_4$ is an extension of $GF(2)$ so it would have elements $0,1,a,a^2$ where $a$ is an element of order 3. Your entries are just integers in $\{0,1,2,3\}$ so this is NOT the generator matrix of a code over $GF(4).$

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DNR version:** It is a nontrivial task to determine how many errors can be corrected.

Generator matrices do not correct any errors; codes with appropriate decoding algorithms do, and not all decoding algorithms can correct *all* the errors that a code is capable of correcting. Be that as it may, *determining* the *minimum distance* of a code (which tells you how many errors the code is *capable* of correcting -- whether or not there is a decoding algorithm capable of correcting that many errors is a separate issue) is nontrivial.  See the paper by Alexander Vardy "The intractability of computing the minimum distance of a code," *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory,* pp. 1757-1766, November 1997 which shows that the problem is NP-hard even for *binary* linear codes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your generator matrix is in standard form, you can find the parity-check matrix easily. Then, by observing the columns, you can detect the minimum distance of this code. Suppose it is d. Then you can correct up to d/2 errors.